# Kafka-s3-connect killed instantly after start

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, aws-msk

I want to connect aws-Kafka with s3 using confluence connector on my ec2 server. I try to configure everything like in tutorials. When I run connect-standalone or connect-distributed, at first everything goes well, I don't get any errors in the logs but after information about connection starting, my connector died instantly without any information. Has anybody got same problem?

config/connect-standalone.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=msk-connection-string
plugin.path=/home/ubuntu/connectors/confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
```

connector.properties

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.bytearray.ByteArrayFormat
flush.size=1

topics=SomeTopic 

s3.bucket.name=bucket-name-here
s3.region=us-west-2
s3.part.size=5242880

aws.access.key.id=****
aws.secret.access.key=****

behavior.on.null.values=ignore

storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
topics.dir=../topics
store.url=http://bucket-name.s3-website-Region.amazonaws.com

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
```

logs:

```
[2021-08-20 06:32:35,954] INFO Kafka version: 2.7.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:119)
[2021-08-20 06:32:35,954] INFO Kafka commitId: 448719dc99a19793 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:120)
[2021-08-20 06:32:35,954] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1629441155953 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:121)
Killed
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

MSK requires TLS connection

When adding few lines with ssl configuration to **config/connect-standalone.properties**

```
producer.security.protocol=SSL
consumer.security.protocol=SSL

security.protocol=SSL
ssl.protocol=TLS
ssl.truststore.location=/your/path/to/truststore/kafka.client.truststore.jks
```

It starts working properly!